# Access url with params that is directly pasted in search bar in next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

So i know how dynamic routing and stuff works when you are navigating from inside the next.js app using  or Router.push(). What I don't understand is say i have a URL:

```
   http://localhost:3000/jhondoe
```

Now i directly paste this URL into the browser. How will next know which page to render? Keep in mind that the Jhondoe part is not exactly a page but a path param that i need to access to display stuff related to Jhon doe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In next you can do something like [id] that is create a folder like this in pages and put your actual page here.